# Expected mock function to have been called -Async

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, jestjs, async.js

Trying to create a test case for the following function. Not familiar with async and await, using Jest and Enzyme for React Js.
 Goal: test to pass properly
And make sure the function is getting called correctly

```js
  async patchPolicy() {
    const { user, services } = this.props;
    const { data } = this.state;
    const body = {
      Policies: [
        {
          Choices: data.Choices || ''
        }
      ]
    };
    PolicyModels.patchWork({
      user,
      services,
      body,
      id: this.state.Policy
    });
    const contextBody = data.WORK_CONTEXT[0];
    const Context_UID = '';
    const method = 'POST';
    if (contextBody) {
      //
      if (contextBody.Context_UID) {
        // If has UID, Patch
        PolicyModels.patchWorkContext({
          user,
          services,
          body: contextBody,
          id: contextBody.Context_UID
        });
      } else {
        contextBody.WorkID = this.state.data.WorkID;
        PolicyModels.patchWorkContext({
          user,
          services,
          body: contextBody,
          id: contextBody.Context_UID
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Created the following test for it but I keep getting this message:

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
>       Expected mock function to have been called.

```js
const patchWorkMock = jest.fn();
PolicyModels.patchWorkContext = patchWorkMock;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter keyLength={0}>
      <EditPolicy {...baseProps} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});

it('Test patchPolicy function', async () => {
  wrapper.setProps({
    services: {},
    user: {}
  });
  wrapper.find('EditPolicy').setState({
    data: {
      Policy: {},
      Description: {},
      Help_UID: {},
      Choices: {},
      WorkID: [],
      WORK_CONTEXT: []
    }
  });
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper
    .find('EditPolicy')
    .instance()
    .patchPolicy();
  expect(patchWorkMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  return wrapper
    .find('EditPolicy')
    .instance()
    .patchPolicy()
    .then(result => {
      expect(result).toBeUndefined();
    });
});
```

Expect the function to get called/ and works properly . I was able to get the test to pass but i believe it did not add anything into its coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as PolicyModels from './PolicyModels';

export interface IEditPolicyProps {
  user: any;
  services: any[];
}

interface IEditPolicyState {
  data: {
    WorkID: string;
    Choices: string;
    WORK_CONTEXT: any[];
  };
  Policy: string;
}

export class EditPolicy extends Component<IEditPolicyProps, IEditPolicyState> {
  constructor(props: IEditPolicyProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        WorkID: '',
        Choices: '',
        WORK_CONTEXT: []
      },
      Policy: ''
    };
  }

  public async patchPolicy() {
    const { user, services } = this.props;
    const { data } = this.state;
    const body = {
      Policies: [
        {
          Choices: data.Choices || ''
        }
      ]
    };
    PolicyModels.patchWork({
      user,
      services,
      body,
      id: this.state.Policy
    });
    const contextBody = data.WORK_CONTEXT[0];
    const Context_UID = '';
    const method = 'POST';
    if (contextBody) {
      //
      if (contextBody.Context_UID) {
        // If has UID, Patch
        PolicyModels.patchWorkContext({
          user,
          services,
          body: contextBody,
          id: contextBody.Context_UID
        });
      } else {
        contextBody.WorkID = this.state.data.WorkID;
        PolicyModels.patchWorkContext({
          user,
          services,
          body: contextBody,
          id: contextBody.Context_UID
        });
      }
    }
  }

  public render() {
    return <div>Expected mock function to have been called -Async</div>;
  }
}
```

`PolicyModels.ts`:

```js
export function patchWork(...args) {}

export function patchWorkContext(...args) {}
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ReactWrapper, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import { EditPolicy, IEditPolicyProps } from './';
import * as PolicyModels from './PolicyModels';

describe('EditPolicy', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;
  const baseProps: IEditPolicyProps = {
    user: {},
    services: []
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter keyLength={0}>
        <EditPolicy {...baseProps} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('Test patchPolicy function with context body', async () => {
    const patchWorkContextSpy = jest.spyOn(PolicyModels, 'patchWorkContext');
    wrapper.find('EditPolicy').setState({
      data: {
        Policy: '',
        Choices: '',
        WorkID: '',
        WORK_CONTEXT: [{ Context_UID: 1 }]
      }
    });
    await (wrapper.find('EditPolicy').instance() as any).patchPolicy();
    expect(patchWorkContextSpy).toBeCalledWith({ user: {}, services: [], body: { Context_UID: 1 }, id: 1 });
  });

  it('Test patchPolicy function without context body', async () => {
    const patchWorkContextSpy = jest.spyOn(PolicyModels, 'patchWorkContext');
    wrapper.find('EditPolicy').setState({
      data: {
        Policy: '',
        Choices: '',
        WorkID: '222',
        WORK_CONTEXT: [{ Context_UID: 0, WorkID: 0 }]
      }
    });
    await (wrapper.find('EditPolicy').instance() as any).patchPolicy();
    expect(patchWorkContextSpy).toBeCalledWith({
      user: {},
      services: [],
      body: { Context_UID: 0, WorkID: '222' },
      id: 0
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56238887/index.spec.tsx (12.167s)
  EditPolicy
    ✓ Test patchPolicy function with context body (60ms)
    ✓ Test patchPolicy function without context body (4ms)

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files        |      100 |     87.5 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 PolicyModels.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx       |      100 |     87.5 |      100 |      100 |                50 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.746s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56238887

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `await` before every call to `patchPolicy` :

```
await wrapper
    .find('EditPolicy')
    .instance()
    .patchPolicy();
```

By the way, a good practice to know if the test is checking every `expect` is to add `expect.assertions` in the first line of the test. For instance, in your case, if you use `expect.assertions(2)`, your test would fail.